# ReactJS does not re-loads my updated component when separate links are clicked from the navbar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-component, react-component-unmount

I have this case where, in the nav bar I have different categories eg Science, business etc. When clicked on ay of these we are supposed to render News component with the appropriate category.

But in my case on clicking on any of the link, although the address bar did change but news component was not being reloaded with the new category that I provided.

Here are my files :

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import News from './components/News';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.category = 'about';
    this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = '';
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavBar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/about">
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/business">
              {this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = this.category = 'business'}
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/entertainment">
              {this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = this.category = 'entertainment'}
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/general">
              {this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = this.category = 'general'}
            </Route>
            <Route exact exactpath="/health">
              {this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = this.category = 'health'}
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/science">
              {this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = this.category = 'science'}
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/sports">
              {this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = this.category = 'sports'}
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/technology">
              {this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent = this.category = 'technology'}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <News key={this.uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent} pageSize={5} country="in" category={this.category}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

**NavBar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";

export class NavBar extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">NewsMonkey</Link>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/business">Business</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/entertainment">Entertainment</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/general">General</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/health">Health</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/science">Science</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">Sports</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/technology">Technology</Link>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NavBar
```

**News.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NewsItem from './NewsItem'
import Spinner from './Spinner'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


export class News extends Component {

    static defaultProps = {
        country: 'in',
        pageSize: 5,
        category: 'general'
    }

    static propTypes = {
        country: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        pageSize: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        category: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            articles:[],
            loading:true,
            page:1,
            totalResults : 0
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=APIKEY&page=1&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
        this.setState({loading: true});
        let data = await fetch(url);
        console.log(data);
        let parsedData = await data.json();
        this.setState({articles: parsedData.articles, totalResults: parsedData.totalResults, loading: false})
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    handlePrevClick = async ()=>{
        let currentPage = this.state.page;
        let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=APIKEY&page=${currentPage-1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
        this.setState({loading: true});
        let data = await fetch(url);
        console.log(data);
        let parsedData = await data.json();
        console.log(parsedData);
        if(parsedData)
            this.setState({articles: parsedData.articles, page : currentPage - 1, loading: false});
            console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleNextClick = async ()=>{
        let currentPage = this.state.page;
        let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=APIKEY&page=${currentPage+1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
        this.setState({loading: true});
        let data = await fetch(url);
        console.log(data);
        let parsedData = await data.json();
        console.log(parsedData);
        if(parsedData)
            this.setState({articles: parsedData.articles, page : currentPage + 1, loading: false});
            console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container my-3">
                <h3 className="text-center">NewsMonkey - Top headlines</h3>
                {this.state.loading && <Spinner/>}
                
                <div className="row">
                {!this.state.loading && this.state.articles.map((element)=>{
                    return (
                    <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                        <NewsItem title={element && element.title?element.title.slice(0, 45): ""} description={element && element.description?element.description.slice(0, 50):""}
                        imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
                        newsUrl ={element.url}/>
                    </div>
                )})}
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex justify-content-between">
                    
                    <button type="button" disabled={this.state.page<=1} className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handlePrevClick} >&larr; Prev</button>
                    <button type="button" disabled={this.props.pageSize*this.state.page>=this.state.totalResults} className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handleNextClick}>Next &rarr;</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default News
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't try to set a variable but just directly put the component

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavBar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/business">
              <News pageSize={5} country="in" category={'business'}/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/entertainment">
              <News pageSize={5} country="in" category={'entertainment'}/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

every time you hit a /business it will render the component that is a child of `<Route exact path="/business">`

if you call /entertainment, it renders the child component you put under `<Route exact path="/entertainment">`

and so on

If you want to make that a bit more "clean", you could create a component that returns a Route

```
const RouteCategory = ({category}) => (
  <>
            <Route exact path={`${'/' + category `}>
              <News pageSize={5} country="in" category={category}/>
            </Route>
  </>
)

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavBar/>
          <Switch>
            {['business', 'entertainment'].map(category => <RouteCategory category={category}>)}
          </Switch>

        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but you get the idea

Comment: how about I use a state to do the same `{this.setState({uniqueKeyForRemountingNewsComponent: 'business', category : 'business'})}`

Comment: you'll get into a rerender loop :/

Comment: Writing news so many times would be so repeatative, I just wanted a one liner clean solution

Comment: you could create a component that returns a Route

Comment: is there no one liner elegant way? I mean writing news component just once

Comment: I updated my answer, you won't get something simpler than the last suggestion I made

Comment: Compressing the router switch will make it a little complex and non easily rwadable, I ll wait for few answers if I don't get a simple one, I ll accept this!

Comment: thanks, Himanshu. I'll be interested if someone finds a better solution. Yeah my first suggestion of copy-pasting the News component under each route is also imo the most readable solution of the 2 I suggested. Also, you don't have to create the RouteCategory component, you could directly return its content inside the map function

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar have you found a better solution to your issue?

Comment: when you navigate to a route like /business, the router renders what's inside `<Route>`...however inside your <Route> component there are no children. Therefore nothing is rendered

Comment: so does that mean it does not even executes the JSX statements inside it? it does not act like a switch case?\

Comment: No it's not a switch case. It executes the js inside but it might be scoped to the <Route> component

Comment: scoped to the route component meaning? because anyway I am using global variables or global function to update the variables

Comment: I didn't write the thing man. IMO it should just display the thing inside route, I don't even understand why you try to go off the rails

Comment: you could open a discussion on the github repo to get advice from the people who wrote the stuff https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions

Comment: its not about finding answers from people who wrote the stuffs, its about how that things is supposed to work, and how its working internally. Its okay if you don't know, I ll try finding answers from other sources

Comment: the thing is supposed to work by rendering what's inside the <Route> component when you access a /route...